# AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute '_get_running_loop'

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, django-channels, django-signals

I am using `channels` to implement WebSockets.
I am trying to send data through websocket from `post_save` django signal.
Below is my code.

**signals.py**

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=CheckIn)
def send_data_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    stats = get_stats()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'dashboard',
            {
                'type': 'send_data',
                'message': stats
            }
        )

    analytics = get_analytics()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'analytic',
            {
                'type': 'send_data',
                'message': analytics
            }
        )
```

**consumers.py**

```py
class DashboardConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'dashboard'

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send_data',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def send_data(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

this same piece of code is working on my local machine(windows) but when i am trying to run this code on server(ubuntu 16.04) i am getting bellow error:

**Traceback**

```
Exception inside application: module 'asyncio' has no attribute '_get_running_loop'
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
        result = coro.throw(exc)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 183, in __call__
        return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
        await inner_instance(receive, send)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
        [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 52, in await_many_dispatch
        await dispatch(result)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 145, in __call__
        return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 373, in wait_for
        return (yield from fut)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
        yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
        future.result()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
        raise self._exception
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/db.py", line 14, in thread_handler
        return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 164, in thread_handler
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 105, in dispatch
        handler(message)
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 39, in websocket_connect
        self.connect()
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/vmsbackend/check_in/consumers.py", line 57, in connect
        self.channel_name
    File "/home/user1/demowebapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 41, in __call__
        if asyncio._get_running_loop() is not None:
    module 'asyncio' has no attribute '_get_running_loop'
```

also when i am sending data normally from `javascript`  `.send()` function it is working normally on server but when `post_save` signal is called then only i get this error on server. this is working fine on my local system.
I tried removing `async_to_sync` from signals then it is not giving error but it is not transmitting data through web socket.
then it is giving:

```
./check_in/signals.py:47: RuntimeWarning: Coroutine'RedisChannelLayer.group_send' was never awaited
'message': analytics
```

I am using pythom 3.5.2 on both local and server.

I don't know whats wrong. is it code or something else. any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the stack trace, `asgiref` is accessing the private asyncio function `_get_running_loop` to obtain functionality equivalent to 3.7's [`get_running_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop) in older Python versions. But you are running 3.5.2 which lacks even the private function.

Try upgrading your Python to 3.6 or 3.7 and things will likely work.